# DQL Query format when field starts with single quote

Tags: domino-appdev-pack

I was trying to query a field that started with a single quote. If the single quote is in the middle of a field value or at the end of a field value, escaping the single quote by using `''` works. But it doesn't work at the start of the field value. Is there some other format or a way to skip that?

Queries tried:
`FirstName = 'Al''exandra'` finds FirstName="Al'exandra"
`FirstName = 'Alexandra'''` finds FirstName = "Alexandra'"
`FirstName = '''Alexandra'` won't find FirstName = "'Alexandra", it throws a bad request.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a bug.  We've created a ticket for it (DADEV-531) and John will be taking a look at it.  Thank you for bringing this to our attention!